# discrepancy in length of Stream column METADATA$ACTION field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Repro steps:

1. Create a stream on table.
2. Create a view on Stream.
3. Desc view.
   Observation
4. Length of column METADATA$ACTION is VARCHAR(1) but when I select the length of column[length(METADATA$ACTION) ] it is coming as 6(value can be INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE).

Can someone please help to explain this discrepancy?

Comment: When I follow these steps it shows `varchar (6)` for streams created a while ago and `varchar (1)` for streams created just before running the describe on the view. It's a likely change in how it's stored to just I, U, D and to preserve compatibility it's dynamically converted to INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

Comment: I think when we create a view on stream(not holding any data) that time METADATA$ACTION column length is 1 and when stream holds data then on creation of view METADATA$ACTION column size is 6.